# QFlags Enum Type Conversion fails all of a sudden

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.7

I've had this code running for quite a while in a library:

```
MyClass::MyClass() 
  : QDialog()
{
    // (...)
    setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint );
    // (...)
}
```

Then, after changing various parts of the library, I get this message all of a sudden:

```
error C2664: 'QWidget::setWindowFlags': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'Qt::WindowFlags'
```

Apparently it doesn't find the | operator overload provided by the QFlags class so that the result of | returns an int rather than a QFlags construct.

I know I could manually cast the result to `(Qt::WindowFlags)` and make it work, but QFlags would usually make this kind of cast unnecessary.

Any idea what kind of change could lead to this behaviour?

I am including `<QtGui/QDialog>` which would usually be sufficient. Including `<QtCore/QFlags>` doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [5.12.0](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.12.0/?h=v5.12.0#n138), this should be fixed by [this commit](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h?id=e759d38d491d9044a0558b1d45911e3b4115e772): "Declare the operator| in the Qt namespace for QFlags in that namespaces". Before 5.12.0, Qt used to put its enum operators in the global namespace (see [qnamespace.h](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qnamespace.h?id=add58edcdbd986e68cdd65a2a935b76d85d5b639#n1733)) instead of in the `Qt` namespace.

The problem is that when there is another operator that matches in the current namespace, the compiler [will not search the parent scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195512/namespaces-and-operator-resolution). Therefore, as soon as you add an overload for an operator for any type in your namespace, Qt's overloads won't be in the set of matches. [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is normally used to resolve operators declared in the same namespace as the type, but this doesn't work if the operators are in a different namespace.

The real solution was for Qt to put operators in the same namespace as the types they operate on, which they did in 5.12.0. If you're stuck with a previous version, you can import the operators yourself:

```
using ::operator|;
setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
```

Note that this may have unintended consequences, as you might be making a lot of names available in a context where they shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Check your source code to see if you use `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` to declare your own flags somewhere in a namespace before where you got the compile error.

As @isanae said, `If there is another operator that matches in the current namespace, ...`. So you should not put the other operator that might be matching.

The solution is to put all your own `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` declaration in global namespace, just as what Qt does.

Hope this could be helpful. I hit the same issue when I put everything into a unity build environment, and I switch the order of source codes and finally located the code snippet that causes this problem: one `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` inside a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to separate the | expression from the function calling? Something like:

```
// ..
Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint;
setWindowFlags( flags );
// ...
```

Just to see where exactly the problem is...

If it's a problem of includes, just do `#include <QtGui>`

Comment: It compiles fine if I split it into two lines like that. Any idea about the difference to my code? Is it maybe the = operator?

Comment: @Fèlix parentheses are unpaired in your example

Comment: @dschulz Thanks! My mistake! Now it's ok.

Comment: @TimMeyer Probably the compiler has a bad time trying to decipher if it must be considered as an `int` or as a `Qt::WindowFlags`. This method avoids the use of type cast.

Comment: `setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowFlags (Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint) );` should also work. I've seen this style in some Qt books.

Comment: Right, you are _instantiating_ a Qt::WindowFlags with the copy constructor, just like mine. Same old friend, but different suit. And yours is a more compact solution, yes.