# Overloading operator | interferes with Qt enum constants

Tags: c++, qt, enums, operator-overloading

I made bit flags using a scoped enum, and I overload `operator |` to combine values:

```
enum class PARAM_T : int {
    NONE = 0x0,
    INPUT = 0x01,
    OUTPUT = 0x02,
    OUTPUT_VECTOR = 0x04
};

inline PARAM_T operator | (PARAM_T lhs, PARAM_T rhs)
{
    using T = std::underlying_type_t<PARAM_T>;
    return (PARAM_T)(static_cast<T>(lhs) | static_cast<T>(rhs));
}
```

Elsewhere in my project, I do some drag/drop operations using Qt widgets, where I use `operator |` to combine some named constants:

```
Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction);
```

The `operator |` here is unrelated to my bit flags, yet for some reason my overload breaks this line of code, giving the following error:

`error C2664: 'Qt::DropAction QDrag::exec(Qt::DropActions,Qt::DropAction)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'Qt::DropActions'`

Why is the compiler matching Qt constants to my overload?  They are entirely different and incompatible types.

Comment: This doesn't look possible. Can you provide an MCVE?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with my MCVE.  I'm trying to figure out what code I have to add to make it fail as it fails in my project.  What about this doesn't look possible, BTW?

Comment: You should use `QFlags` and then you'll get type safety and operators, even on C++98.

Comment: It works fine with Qt 5.5/mingw 4.9.2/std=c++14 flag. "What about this doesn't look possible?": your issue, precisely because "They are entirely different types" (you can use `static_cast<>` though). It is suggested to use `QFlags` as a workaround, not to abandon the enum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QFlags Enum Type Conversion fails all of a sudden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755058/qflags-enum-type-conversion-fails-all-of-a-sudden)

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on the subject of flags, I see that there are arguments against using enums as flags, so I changed my enum to this:

```
namespace PARAM {
    const int NONE =            0;
    const int INPUT =           1 << 0;
    const int OUTPUT_SCALAR =   1 << 1;
    const int OUTPUT_VECTOR =   1 << 2;
}
```

Now I can use the default implementations of `operator |`, `operator &`, etc, instead of my overloads, and Qt is happy again.  This is more of a work-around than an answer; I'd still like to know why the compiler was using my overload for the Qt constants.