# C++ Overloaded function name lookup error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, name-lookup

I encountered a strange error regarding name lookup in C++.

The error can be recreated using the following minimal example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& a) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        out << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return out;
}

namespace Test {

    struct A {
        // Label 1
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A&) {
            return out << "A" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    struct B {
        void printVector() noexcept {
            std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
            std::cout << v << std::endl; // The error occurs in this line
        }
        // Label 2
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const B&) {
            return out << "B" << std::endl;
        }
    };

}

int main() {
    Test::B().printVector();
}
```

Compiling this will result in the following error message:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

You can test this for yourself here: http://cpp.sh/5oya

The strange part is, that the code compiles and runs fine if you remove either one of the functions labeled with `// Label 1` respectively `// Label 2`.

My question now is: What is going on here? How can it be fixed?

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99865250debbfc32)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 produces this error message : "error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: g++ version 5.3.1 produces this error message : `Error: no match for »operator<<« (operand types are »std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}« and »std::vector<int>«)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Namespaces and operator resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195512/namespaces-and-operator-resolution)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MinGW g++ 6.3.0, but Visual C++ 2015 has sort of the same error. Like the online g++ 4.9.2 you used it considers only `basic_ostream::operator<<` and `std::operator<<`. Which is weird. Weirder: it does find the overload if it's placed in namespace `Test`, i.e. it *does* look in outer namespaces, not just class and ADL. And this happens also with the online g++ 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other workaround will be to overload operator << inside the namespace std, instead of in the global namespace.(The lookup will find it at namespace scope)

```
namespace std
{
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& a) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            out << a[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Try [Here](http://cpp.sh/9l4x)

[EDITED]

Another workaround, and for puritan people that don't want to pollute global namespace, or the `std`, is to

> ...have the insertion operators in the same namespace as the class upon
>   which it operates.

...as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195512/namespaces-and-operator-resolution).

```
namespace Test
{
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int>& a) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            out << a[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Working code [here](http://cpp.sh/7jndd).

Comment: I don't like that this requires to extend the std namespace. But using this work around does not require to change the calling code, so I will use this solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rama, This solution actually invokes Undefined Behavior, hence it *"doesn't work**. You may specialize any template in the `std::` namespace, but you are not permitted to overload any function in `std::` nemespace. The  ISO C++ standard [invokes Undefined behavior to any C++ program that adds anything to](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-1) the `std::` namespace.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Ohh!! so you think that doing naked at the global scope it is more scoped than in a particular namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You are having ADL troubles, though I think name lookup should have found your overload in the global namespace. *(I don't have specific C++ standard quotes to know if the compiler is wrong yet)*. GCC (version 6.3) and Clang (version 3.8.0) compilers finds the overload as seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a63aa69a40dde7e1)

One work around is to import the `name` of the global operator into your current namespace:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
using ::operator <<; 
std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

As seen here: http://cpp.sh/95kuq

Another work around will be to explicitly call the global overload like:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
::operator << (std::cout,  v); 
std::cout << std::endl;
```

As seen here: http://cpp.sh/4btyq

Comment: Yes, this works, but it removes the beauty of using overloaded operators.

Comment: @zuenni, well, you could simply import the global operator like `using ::operator<<;` as seen [here](http://cpp.sh/95kuq). I've revised my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. Both indeed do work. But I prefer a solution, where the calling code can be kept unchanged and looks like one would expect it to look.