# Operator overloading, name resolution and namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I would like some light to be shed on a puzzling situation involving ADL, namespaces and operator overloading.

Let Foo be a library which defines a class ( `Deriv`)  in its own namespace, along with a templated `operator *` which returns another class.

```
namespace Foo {
    class Deriv {};
    class Another {};

    template <typename T>
    Another operator* ( T x, const Deriv& d ) { return Another();}
}
```

Now I use Foo's class in my own library Bar, which defines another `operator *`, this time only for `float`.

```
namespace Bar {
    typedef Foo::Deriv MyDeriv;
    MyDeriv operator* (float x, const MyDeriv& d) { return MyDeriv();}
}
```

I observe a difference in compiler behaviour depending whether one is inside `namespace Bar` or not.

This function (`Bar::f1`) compiles, using the second version of the `operator *` :

```
namespace Bar {
    void f1() {
        Bar::MyDeriv a;
        Bar::MyDeriv b = 3.f * a;
    }
}
```

while the same function outside namespace Bar (`f2()`) fails to compile, because the compiler attempts only to use `Foo::operator*` and cannot guess that it must use `Bar::operator*`.

```
void f2() {
    Bar::MyDeriv a; 
    Bar::MyDeriv b = 3.f * a; // Error : cannot convert Foo:Another to Bar::Myderiv
}
```

You can see the code live here :http://ideone.com/pkPeOY

Now, if `Foo::operator*` was not templated and defined as `Foo::operator*(float, const Deriv& d);` then *both* functions fail to compile with the same error (ambiguous operator overload), as can be seen here : http://ideone.com/wi1EWS

So, facing this situation, this is what is puzzling me

- In the *templated* case, when compiling `f2`, the compiler considers using `Foo::operator*` but not `Bar::operator*`, while in the *non-templated* case, it considers using both (and refuses to go further because of the ambiguity). *What makes the compiler behave differently ?*
- A user of my library Bar will be outside the `Bar::` namespace, yet I want `Bar::operator*` to be used, and not `Foo::operator*`. I considered explicitely calling `Bar::operator*(3.f,a)`, which is ugly, or inserting my own operator in the global namespace, which I reckon is a [Bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171862/namespaces-and-operator-overloading-in-c#171869) [Thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623631/where-should). *Is there an option I am missing, or am I doing something wrong ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the templated case, when compiling `f2`, the compiler considers using `Foo::operator*` but not `Bar::operator*`, while in the non-templated case, it considers using both (and refuses to go further because of the ambiguity). What makes the compiler behave differently ?

In both cases the compiler considers using both, but in the case of a templated `operator*`, the call is not ambiguous since there is a non-templated function which parameter types perfectly matches the arguments (try replace `3.f` with `3.` and you will see that the templated version is found). Typically:

```
template <typename T>
void g (T) { }

void g (float) { }

g(0.f); // Ok, the overload for float is preferred over the templated version
```

> A user of my library Bar will be outside the `Bar::` namespace, yet I want `Bar::operator*` to be used, and not Foo::operator*. I considered explicitely calling `Bar::operator*(3.f,a)`, which is ugly, or inserting my own operator in the global namespace, which I reckon is a Bad Thing. Is there an option I am missing, or am I doing something wrong ?

Unfortunately, ADL will not find your overload since the only parameters of `operator*` are `float` and `MyDeriv` which are defined inside the namespace `Foo`. One possible way would be to inherit from `Foo::Deriv`:

```
namespace Bar {
    struct MyDeriv: public Foo::Deriv {};
    MyDeriv operator* (float x, const MyDeriv& d) { return MyDeriv();}
}
```

Another one is to declare your overload for `operator*` inside the `Foo` namespace:

```
namespace Bar {
    typedef Foo::Deriv MyDeriv;
}

namespace Foo {
    Bar::MyDeriv operator* (float x, const Bar::MyDeriv& d) { return Bar::MyDeriv(); }
}
```

Comment: @GuyGreer If there is nothing virtual in `Foo::Deriv`, I think there will be no downside in term of size (and a good compiler should optimize everything out, I guess... ).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I thought the derived class needed to have its own address...  I think I should keep to myself today, I'm not on my game.

Comment: Yeh sorry about the confusion. at first I thought it was because Deriv was actually part of a CRTP (thus a derived class) but it was unrelevant to the problem, so I removed the inheritance (but kept the name, which can be confusing).