# Can I namespace the ostream << operator?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-keyword

As has been answered before, [namespacing operator overloads is considered good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171862/namespaces-and-operator-overloading-in-c), so that's what I want to do.

Problem: It only compiles if I don't. Am I just doing it wrong, or have I found an exception where it is not possible?

Here is a single translation unit for easy repro:

```
// lib/halfseconds.h:
#include <chrono>

namespace lib {
    using halfseconds = std::chrono::duration<intmax_t, std::ratio<1, 2> >;
}

// lib/debug.h:
#include <ostream>

namespace lib {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, lib::halfseconds halves)
    {
        double seconds = halves.count();
        seconds /= lib::halfseconds::period::den;
        o << seconds << 's';
        return o;
    }
}

// demo/main.cpp:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    lib::halfseconds threeHalvseconds(3);
    std::cout << threeHalvseconds << '\n'; // 1.5s
}
```

What does the compiler say? G++ version 8.2.1 says «no match for operator<<» and spews one daunting list (208 lines) of candidates. I suppose none of those are relevant, as I wouldn't get this error if the relevant one wasn't missing.

Comment: One difference between this and the question it is marked as duplicating seems to be that putting `operator<<` in namespace lib in this case doesn't solve the problem in the same way it does the other question.

Comment: No. "namespace" is a noun. You can't verb it.

Comment: I can verb "space", therefore I can verb "namespace".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle you're trying to use is called [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). If I have a function and a type declared in the same namespace, I can use them together outside of the namespace without having to specify which namespace the function is from:

```
//In MyClass.h
namespace foo {
    class MyClass { /* stuff */ }; 
}
//In doStuff.h
namespace foo {
    void doStuff(MyClass c) { /* stuff */ }
}

//in main.cc
int main() {
    foo::MyClass tom; //I'm bad with names
    doStuff(tom); //Here, we don't have to specify the namespace
}
```

This is *almost* what's happening in your example. The difference is that `halfseconds` isn't actually declared in namespace `lib`. Because `halfseconds` is an alias, it's actually declared in `std::chrono`, and when you put the `operator<<` overload in namespace `lib`, the compiler doesn't check for it.

## How to fix this

The simplest way to fix this is to declare a new type in namespace lib:

```
// lib/halfseconds.h:
#include <chrono>

namespace lib {
    class halfseconds 
        : public std::chrono::duration<intmax_t, std::ratio<1, 2>> 
    {
       public:
        using Base = std::chrono::duration<intmax_t, std::ratio<1, 2>>;
        using Base::Base; //Use the constructor
    };
}

// lib/debug.h:
#include <ostream>

namespace lib {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, lib::halfseconds halves)
    {
        double seconds = halves.count();
        seconds /= lib::halfseconds::period::den;
        o << seconds << 's';
        return o;
    }
}

// demo/main.cpp:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    lib::halfseconds threeHalvseconds(3);
    std::cout << threeHalvseconds << '\n'; // 1.5s
}
```

You can use it anywhere you'd use `std::chrono::duration`, it has all the same functionality, and because it's defined in the `lib` namespace it can be used with any other functions in the `lib` namespace without having to prefix `lib`!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that once you have put operator<< in a namespace, you should explicitly tell the compiler you would like to use the namespace, otherwise it's hidden.

Either:

- using lib::operator<< inside the main
- lib::operator<<(std::cout, threeHalvseconds) << '\n';

Comment: Upvoted, but here is additional information:  When this code gets upgraded to C++20, the first bullet will cause a conflict because C++20 adds a streaming operator for `lib::halfseconds` (which is a type alias for `std::chrono::duration`).  The fix will be to remove `lib::operator<<`, though the syntax of the output will then change to `3[1/2]s`.